# How to subscribe 1000 pubnub channels from the client?

Tags: pubnub

I have a web client using pubnub, and there are 1000 channels need to be subscribed. But once I call pubnub.subscribe(allChannels), the server returns 500.

I did not find any limit saying why it cannot.

Comment: Please read the [help] before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no hard limit on the number of channels you can subscribe to.  But if you are going to subscribe to more than 20-30 channels, it's usually recommended to use Channel Groups instead, which allows you to create a collection of channels and give that collection a name.  Then, your client simply subscribes to the Channel Group instead of the individual channels.  https://www.pubnub.com/developers/tech/key-concepts/stream-controller/channel-groups/

Answer (score 2):

## Subscribe to 1,000 Channels and Beyond

> You already know the list of channels you want to subscribe to, **[Channel Groups](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/advanced-channel-groups)** will help you get to 2,000 channels per group.  There are also some options to subscribe to an **unlimited number of channels** using wildcards!
>
> You can have **2,000 channels per [channel group](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/advanced-channel-groups)**.  This matches your need for 1,000 channel subscription.
>
> Also remember that [Security is important](https://www.pubnub.com/products/security-overview/). Remember that you should secure your data.

More channel subscription options below for your consideration.

## Channel Subscription Options

For the PubNub SDKs 4.0 and higher.  Multiplexing the SDK supports up to around **50 channels practically**.  You can increase this number further but device performance will be impacted.  It is better to utilize the **Channel Group** feature of the core [PubNub Stream Controller](http://www.pubnub.com/products/stream-controller/) product.  Stream Controller includes the following channel subscription enhancements.

### Wildcard Subscribe

***Maximum Addressable Channels: ( Unlimited )***

PubNub Also supports [Wildcard Subscriptions using a Hierarchical dot notation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#subscribe_example_wildcard).  Today in PubNub you can subscribe to channel **`"a.b.*"`** and receive messages at any channel below `a.b`.  You could publish to channel **`"a.b.c"`** and receive the message in your wildcard subscribe.  Note that the maximum depth supported of the hierarchy is currently a depth of **three**.  For example **`"a.b.*"`** is good but **`"a.b.c.*"`** is not supported.

### Channel Groups

***Maximum Addressable Channels: ( 2,000 ✕ 10 ＝ 20,000 )***

Dynamically control the device's data stream feed with PubNub Channel Groups.  You can remotely control which streams the device is subscribed to and dynamically **add** and **remove** channels from the list of channels.  You can multiplex subscribe up to 10 channel groups and each channel group can contain up to 2,000 channels.

### Multiplexing

***Maximum Addressable Channels: ( ~50-500 )***

You can multiplex your connection by subscribing to a combination of **Wildcard Channels**, **Channel Groups**, **Presence Event Stream Channels** and more.  It is recommended to keep your multiplexed channels below 50 for best device performance.

### Stream Filtering

***Maximum Addressable Channels: ( Unlimited )***

[Stream Filter](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/stream-filtering-tutorial) allows a subscriber to apply a filter to only receive messages that satisfy the conditions of the filter. The message filter is set by the subscribing client(s) but it is applied on the server side thus preventing unwanted messages (those that do not meet the conditions of the filter) from reaching the subscriber. Stream Filters are implemented with two components: meta dictionary on publish and filter expression on subscribe. Filters are applied to all channels that the client is subscribed to. When messages are encrypted (using crypto key when initializing PubNub), the meta dictionary is plain text, so that the PubNub Network can properly apply the filters as required. It is important to only include information that is not confidential or otherwise requiring encryption.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit number of subscribed channels, that's what I have tested: **640** channels. And once subscribed 640 channels, it is still successful, but if you subscribe one more, errors will start happening (server returns 500) and all your pubnub connection will get destroyed.

It seems you can subscribe many more channels at one time (Its official website suggest **50** channels, but I have tried subscribed 400 channels at one time and it is successful)

So total limit **640** is what I have found.

Comment: Xin, please see my answer below...the reason you may have seen a limit of 640 channels is probably due to the name length of the channels, and the subsequent length of the URI for the subscribe.  Channel Groups is the way to go here....and please contact support@pubnub.com if you need more help.

Comment: Xin, Todd is right. There is no "hard" limit, it's due to the URI limit with HTTP. So the total number of chars of all of you channels is the limit (plus other URI path and query param chars). So channel groups allows you to keep that list of channels on the PubNub server side with a Channel Group name that "points" to that list of channels. You can have up to 2000 channels per Channel Group and each user (device) can subscribe to 10 channel groups for a total of 20K channels.  Is that enough for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to correct the syntax.

```
pubnub.subscribe({
   channels:allChann
})
```